# Facebook login doesn't work when device has older version of facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Facebook SDK 3.5 integration with android app doesn't work with android when the device has an older version of the facebook app. My application integrates with the fb login. The user logins with success, but after that the following message appears :

```
"The page you requested cannot be displayed at the moment ......."
```

And if I update the Facebook app, it will login smoothly with the user's data... 
I have tested it with facebook example : scrumptious , this problem occurs to me in that example too.

```
Steps :
1. Select login with facebook (Device has install facebook app version 1.8.3)
2. User fill necessary details and logged in
3. Message appears in pink box 
"The page you requested cannot be displayed at the moment ......."
```

After that, if the facebook app is updated, the above flow works smoothly

Comment: I had the same problem, seems to be a facebook bug, not sure what you could do here cause the facebook app should show a message about updating your app